# Packaging Smoke tests as an (additional) executable jar in Gradle build

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, spring-boot, smoke-testing

We have a gradle build creating a SpringBoot web application. The SpringBoot app is tested with a variety of tests including a suite of WebDriver 'journey' tests. We run a subset of these journey tests as 'smoke' tests on different environments.

To make this as simple as possible we want to create an executable FatJar (or similar) consisting of a Main class, the smoke tests and testing dependencies. This artifact should be created in addition to the main application jar and can then be run against an arbitrary environment from the command line.

What's the best way of achieving this? Sub-projects don't seem to fit because we want to package the 'test' output from a single project. The [spring-boot gradle plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) seems to be (rightly) geared to producing a single application artifact, is there a way to MacGyver it to create another executable jar with the smoke tests? Is this just crazy talk?